# Mupen64 not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: games, emulation, ubuntu-emulator

I have installed both Mupen64Plus-Qt and M64Py straight from the ubuntu store.

For m64Py it says library for Mupen Plus 64 not found, i dont know where to find the library file.

i have found this but i dont know how to download it
https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-core

```
***/usr/local/bin/mupen64plus --nosaveoptions --datadir /usr/local/share/mupen64plus --plugindir /usr/local/lib/mupen64plus --noosd --windowed "/home/ahmad/Downloads/emus/Legend of Zelda, The - Ocarina of Time (U) (V1.2) [!].z64"

http://code.google.com/p/mupen64plus/  
Mupen64Plus Console User-Interface Version 1.99.1

UI-console: attached to core library 'Mupen64Plus Core' version 2.5.0
            Includes support for Dynamic Recompiler.
            Includes support for MIPS r4300 Debugger.
Core Error: CoreStartup(): Front-end (API version 1.0.0) is incompatible with this core (API 2.1.1)
UI-console: error starting Mupen64Plus core library.***
```

Answer (score 1):

If those don't work for you, loganmc10 has provided a zip file on GitHub with what you need to get started.

Install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt install qt5-default libqt5websockets5 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-net-2.0-0 libhidapi-hidraw0 libminizip1 p7zip-full
```

Go to:

https://github.com/loganmc10/m64p/releases

Download and unzip the Linux version, change into the directory created, and run the gui frontend:

```
./mupen64plus_gui
```

It should already be executable, but if it's not run:

```
chmod u+x mupen64plus_gui
```

Repo:

https://github.com/loganmc10/m64p